# NUMA domain(Equal node binding among All the processes) can not increase throughput why?

Tags: cpu-usage

I have run 15 processes on linux system. System architecture have 40 core CPU on 2 Node(0 And 1). each process contains 2 application threads.

Without doing NUMA node binding with processes, I have achieved 92% CPU utilization with a specific load on processes.

With NUMA node Binding(8 process on node 0 and 7 process on node 1) of all processes; system is not able to handle more load than above scenario while CPU utilization is less(85%) in this scenario. why system can not able to handle more load as CPU utilization is less than previous scenario?

Comment: A couple of question first: are you running 15 (heavy weight) processes or 15 (light weight) threads? Are these identical processes? What do you mean by "system can not handle more load"? Are all the processes CPU bound?

Comment: 15 Heavy weight processes; 
ALL processes are identical; 
"system can not handle more load" means the no of requests are being served by the server in both cases are same...It should be increased when running the processes with Node Binding because in this case CPU utilization is less(i.e. 85%) from previous scenario(i.e. 92%). 
Processes are Node bounded using numactl --cpunodebind=0 --membind=0 pocess1_exe; numactl --cpunodebind=1 --membind=1 pocess2_exe likewise –

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: BACKGROUND: Node binding works because the CPU utilization is less. QUESTION: Why is the server unable to run more processes in the same interval of time?